# Why does c++ compiler not warn about returning reference to local variable?

Tags: c++, lvalue

In below code, compiler warns about returning reference to local when bar() method is called. I was expecting similar warning about foo() method as well.

```
#include <iostream>

class Value {
public:
    int& foo() {
        int tc = 10;
        int& r_tc = tc;
        return r_tc;
    }

    int& bar() {
        int tc = 10;
        return tc;
    }
};

int main() {
    Value value;
    int& foo_ref = value.foo();
    int& bar_ref = value.bar();
    std::cout << foo_ref << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output of compilation:

```
g++ -c refreturn.cc -g -std=c++1z; g++ -o refreturn refreturn.o
refreturn.cc: In member function ‘int& Value::bar()’:
refreturn.cc:12:13: warning: reference to local variable ‘tc’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
         int tc = 10;
             ^

Compilation finished at Sat Mar 23 07:29:31
```

Comment: If you go to the trouble to set up your own reference, it needs to give you the benefit of the doubt. I think you're asking too much of the compiler. :)

Comment: Technically, the standard doesn't require a warning in either case.   You're just lucky that your compiler gives a warning in one of them.   The reason it gives a warning in `bar()` is because someone (or some people) involved in developing the compiler went out of their way to make it do so.   The reason it doesn't give a warning in `foo()` is because no one has yet gone out of their way to make the compiler give a warning.   Why the difference?  Because compiler developers aren't any more perfect than anyone else.

Comment: [What compiler?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc0fe7a6d963dfd0) It is not required to diagnose either error. If you feel this QoA issue in your compiler should be fixed, file a bug.

Comment: @n.m. It is g++ compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Why does c++ compiler not warn about returning reference to local variable?"

Because compilers are not perfect and ultimately it is *your* responsibility to not write invalid code. The compiler is not obligated to warn on everything that is wrong (in fact, it's obligated to warn on *very little*, but most try to do better than the minimal requirement).

Comment: in fact, warnings are "optimistic", to avoid false alarms, the exact opposite of code checking / static code analysers.